# How to replace sed backreference with dyamic variable

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, environment-variables

I need to replace a string with a vars existent in my environment.

For example, I have the following vars in my environment now:

```
export APP_NAME=teste
export DB_DATABASE=dbname
export DB_USER=username
```

Then, I need to replace a string with the value from these vars, for example:

```
echo "APP_NAME=APP_NAME; DB_DATABASE=DB_DATABASE; DB_USER=DB_USER;" | sed -E "s/\b(\w+)\b=(\1)/\1=`echo \\${\\2}`/g"
```

Then the final result that I expect:

```
APP_NAME=teste; DB_DATABASE=dbname; DB_USER=username;
```

But everything that I got is:

```
APP_NAME=${APP_NAME}
DB_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
DB_USER=${DB_USER}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `envsubst`:

```
echo "APP_NAME=APP_NAME; DB_DATABASE=DB_DATABASE; DB_USER=DB_USER;" | sed 's/=/="$/g;s/;/";/g' | envsubst
```

Output:

```
APP_NAME="teste"; DB_DATABASE="dbname"; DB_USER="username";
```

---

See: `man envsubst`

Comment: Wow! This is amazing! I never heard about "envsubst". Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

With any POSIX awk:

```
$ echo "APP_NAME=APP_NAME; DB_DATABASE=DB_DATABASE; DB_USER=DB_USER;" |
    awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS=";"; FS=OFS="="} /=/{$2=ENVIRON[$2]; print}'
APP_NAME=teste; DB_DATABASE=dbname; DB_USER=username;
```